# C# Binding for Objective-C: @property (strong, nonatomic) void (^animations)(void);

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

How should I declare the following property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) void (^animations)(void);
```

in a C# binding (ApiDefinitions.cs) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a smoke it became obvious :-)

**outside** interface:

```
delegate void animationsBlock();
```

**inside** interface:

```
[Export("animations")]
        animationsBlock animations { get; set;}
```